# Java 'throws' keyword in Dart

Tags: exception, flutter, dart, throws

Im coming from a Java background where I use the throws keyword to lead an exception to the method calling another method. How can I do that I dart?

Method called:

```
  void _updateCurrentUserEmail() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .currentUser()
        .then((FirebaseUser user) {
      _email = user.email;
    });
  }
```

How it is called:

```
try {
  _updateCurrentUserEmail();
} on Exception {
  return errorScreen("No User Signed In!", barActions);
}
```

But it seems like the Exception is not caught, because I still get a NoSuchMethodException and the errorScreen is not shown.

Comment: Use `catch` to catch the error

Comment: @Benjamin But I warnt toll catch it in the second method calling _updateCurrentUserEmail. I dont want to react on the exception in the method itself, but in the method calling it(like above)

Comment: Just use `throw` to throw an error in the method. I'm a bit confused otherwise.

Comment: @Benjamin So you mean catch the exception and throw it again?

Comment: Dart has a keyword called `rethrow` so you can throw it again after you catch

Answer (score 2):

While you correctly used try/catch, the exception is coming from an async function that you did not await.

try/catch only catch exceptions thrown *within* that block. But since you wrote:

```dart
try {
  doSomethingAsyncThatWillTrowLater();
} catch (e) {

}
```

Then the exception thrown by the async method is thrown *outside* of the body of `try` (as `try` finished before the async function did), and therefore not caught.

Your solution is to either use `await`:

```dart
try {
  await doSomethingAsyncThatWillTrowLater();
} catch (e) {

}
```

Or use `Future.catchError`/`Future.then`:

```dart
doSomethingAsyncThatWillTrowLater().catchError((error) {
  print('Error: $error');
});
```

Comment: The second option would be great, but I can't do method().catchError...

Comment: Sorry, but I have another question.I am calling the method in the build method. If I am using the second option, the changes would be made after the return statement, which leads to the same result. But I can't use the second option, because I can't make the build method async.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
try {
  _updateCurrentUserEmail();
} on Exception catch(e){
    print('error caught: $e')
}
```

Another way to handle error is to do the following:

```
void _updateCurrentUserEmail() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .currentUser()
        .then((FirebaseUser user) {
      _email = user.email;
      throw("some arbitrary error");
    });
   .catchError(handleError);
  }

handleError(e) {
    print('Error: ${e.toString()}');
  }
```

> If currentUser()’s Future completes with a value, then()’s callback fires. If code within then()’s callback throws (as it does in the example above), then()’s Future completes with an error. That error is handled by catchError().

Check the docs:

https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#throw),

> If the catch clause does not specify a type, that clause can handle any type of thrown object:

```
try {
  breedMoreLlamas();
} on OutOfLlamasException {
  // A specific exception
  buyMoreLlamas();
} on Exception catch (e) {
  // Anything else that is an exception
  print('Unknown exception: $e');   <------------------
} catch (e) {
  // No specified type, handles all
  print('Something really unknown: $e');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Throw**

Here’s an example of throwing, or raising, an exception:

```
throw FormatException('Expected at least 1 section');
```

You can also throw arbitrary objects:

```
throw 'Out of llamas!';
```

throwing an exception is an expression, you can throw exceptions in => statements, as well as anywhere else that allows expressions:

```
void someMethod(Point other) => throw UnimplementedError();
```

here is example

```
main() { 
   try { 
      test_age(-2); 
   } 
   catch(e) { 
      print('Age cannot be negative'); 
   } 
}  
void test_age(int age) { 
   if(age<0) { 
      throw new FormatException(); 
   } 
}
```

hope it helps..